# Binding to attached property of property in style

Tags: wpf, xaml

Before I begin, my end goal here is to have a default ToolTip style for all controls which has a normal border that goes red when there's a validation error on the control for which the ToolTip is being shown.

So ToolTip has a PlacementTarget property which is the control over which the ToolTip is being shown.  There is a Validation.HasError attached property that gets set on that PlacementTarget control when it has a databinding error.  For instance I've got a TextBox, and in the TextBox style I can do this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ToolTip Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
```

Now, I can just make a style for the ToolTip with a red border and set it in that trigger above, but I'd rather not have to do this in every control's style triggers, so I want my ToolTip style to handle this functionality itself if possible.

I've tried various things, most recently this (the converter basically returns red if there's an error, black if not):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Validation.HasError, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource ToolTipBorderConverter}}"/>
</Style>
```

But from the error that gives it looks like that's trying to get an actual property called Validation on the TextBox, as opposed to the attached property:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Validation' property not found on 'object' ''TextBox' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=PlacementTarget.Validation.HasError; DataItem='ToolTip' (Name=''); target element is 'ToolTip' (Name=''); target property is 'BorderBrush' (type 'Brush')
```

I also tried something like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="PlacementTarget.Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
```

But I get an error saying I can't nest the Trigger's property like that.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Thanks, found this right at the same time!

Answer (score 2):

Searched for an answer for this for hours, and right after posting I saw a related article that got me the answer: you have to wrap Validation.HasError in parentheses for it to recognize it as an attached property.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.(Validation.HasError), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource ToolTipBorderConverter}}"/>
```